# OneHotEncoder Python

Tags: python

Llevo intentando resolver este bug hace varios días. El código corresponde a un curso de udemy de data science. Si alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

Primero importe un archivo excel que le puse nombre

```
dataset
y= dataset.iloc[:,4].values #tomay la columna numero 1
Z= dataset.iloc[:,:-1]
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
onehotencoder= OneHotEncoder(categories =lista)
Z = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
print(Z)
```

No puedo convertir las variables categóricas state a dummy porque me sale este error

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: ¡Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los _stack traces_. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Camila, hay varias cosas que debes arreglar en tu código. De partida, ¿de donde apareció X? ¿Por qué con el resultado de OneHotEncoder estás sobrescribiendo Z?¿De dónde proviene `lista`?¿Qué valores posee?

Lo que hace OneHotEncoder es transformar una variable categórica en una matriz de 0s y 1s, donde cada columna representa una categoría y cada fila una observación. Vas a tener *n* columnas como cantidad de valores únicos que tengas en `y`.

Lo otro, `.fit()` espera una array como entrada, así que debes cambiar la forma de la lista para ser admitida en la función. Por ejemplo, para un conjunto de datos aleatorios:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))
df['I'] = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], size=len(df))

y = df.iloc[:, -1]
X = df.iloc[:, :-1]

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(y.values.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
```

De tu conjunto de datos, debes separar la variable dependiente (`y`) de las independientes (`X`) y luego aplicar la transformación. En tu caso, sería algo como:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder()
y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(dataset.iloc[:,4].values.reshape(-1,1)).toarray()
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta. X era la array de mi dataframe. Debo cambiarlo a Z, porque decidí cambiar los datos. Mis variables categórica provienen del array z columna 3 con valores "California", "New York" y "Florida". Los cuales debo transformarlos en valores dummy, sin embargo, al realizarlo me señala el error de que si las categorías son un array debe ser de tamaño de n_características, eso no comprendo. Gracias

Comment: Añade el resultado de la impresión de la variable categórica para que podamos entender mejor el problema

Comment: ([[165349.2, 136897.8, 471784.1, 'New York'],
       [162597.7, 151377.59, 443898.53, 'California']] Z es un array su cuarta columna es la variable categorica. en python la numero 3, lo que quiero hacer es tomar ese array y que solo la columna categorica la transforme en dummy

Comment: Camila, tienes un array. El ejemplo que di es para un dataframe, por lo que debes adaptar el código